# Does execution stack and thread's stack and local variable list refer to different stacks?

Tags: c#, stack, clr, il

A value type may be stored in a thread's stack, and IL runs in the execution stack (abstract concept).

```
int y=0;
int a=0;
int b=0;

int x = y + (a - b);

IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // y
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0004:  stloc.1     // a
IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0006:  stloc.2     // b
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // y
IL_0008:  ldloc.1     // a
IL_0009:  ldloc.2     // b
IL_000A:  sub         
IL_000B:  add         
IL_000C:  stloc.3     // x
```

Now the `stloc.0` pops the value from the execution stack and stored into a local variable list. So, the local variable list must be stored in a different space other than the execution stack. What is the local variable list? Is it a thread's stack?

Also, which stack does the `.maxstack = 3` refer to for a method? Is it the size of the local variable list? or the max size of additional storage pushed into the execution stack?

It seems to me that the execution stack is the proper stack, as it only supports `push` and `pop`. The local variable list supports `load` from an index and `store` to an index. How would that be related to the stack?

#### Update:

**ECMA 335 I.12.3 Machine state** clearly answered my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lasse's answer is quite good; I just want to emphasize a few of his points.

First, C# is translated into an equivalent IL program, and then the IL program is translated into an equivalent machine code program. The IL language has the concept of an evaluation stack; **this is purely a concept in the IL language**. All that is required is that the jitter translate that IL *into machine code that has the same final result*. There is no requirement whatsoever that the jitter actually use the "real" stack just because the IL program was written to use an "evaluation stack".

Basically, IL is a language which assumes an extremely simplified kind of processor; there are no "registers" in IL, only stack.  In a real processor of course there are registers, and so of course the machine-code translation of the IL will not slavishly follow its usage of an evaluation stack; that would be silly.

The "max stack" refers to the "abstract" stack of the IL language; it has no particular connection to the actual thread's stack in the machine code.

I've written a number of articles about the meaning of "the stack" and why we use IL; you might want to check them out if this subject interests you:

- [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail, Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx)
- [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail, Part Two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx)
- [The Truth About Value Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx)
- [Why IL?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/11/18/why-il.aspx)
- [Why have a stack?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/11/28/why-have-a-stack.aspx)

Comment: I understand it is merely an abstract concept. What I don't get is how to relate local variable list and execution stack. `stloc.0` pops value from execution stack and pushes into local variable list, which means these 2 refer to difference spaces (or does it mean to insert the values into the middle of execution stack?). Say, the execution stack is stackA (virtually), and local variable list lives in stackB (virtually), then which one is THE stack we normally say?

Comment: @colinfang: Variables are storage locations. Those storage locations might be taken from the *short term pool* or from the *long term pool*. A *local* variable *at the IL level* is always taken from the short term pool. (This is not true of C#, but it is true of IL.)  The *execution stack* is a "scratch area" for storing temporary values during the execution of a method. So *logically* they are completely separate; they need not have anything whatsoever to do with each other. As a practical matter, it is very natural to implement both with space on the thread's stack.

Comment: @colinfang: People who are used to traditional machine architectures running traditional languages like C tend to lump the storage for locals, the storage for temporaries, and *the return address* as all part of the same activation record on the stack, but it's just an accident of history that this is the traditional way to do it. A thread could -- and in my opinion *should* -- have *two* stacks, one for the data parts of the activation record, and one for the return address. Had the original implementations of C done that, there would be no buffer overrun attack.

Answer (score 5):

Local variables are *typically* stored on the stack. What happens is that at the start of the method, a number of bytes are reserved on the stack, and the local variables lives inside those bytes. Before the method returns, the stack space reserved is "unreserved", and thus the variables are removed from the stack.

The "local variable list" are those variables that live inside that reserved space.

The benefit of this is that a method can call itself without worrying about tripping over the variables in the previous method call, which presumably is still needed when the inner method call returns.

However, there is something else at play here as well. You're referring to IL code, which is "machine code" written for a virtual computer. Not the kind of virtual computer running under VMware or similar, but a virtual computer that does not really exist. There is no CPU available that will run the IL code, like the one you posted in the question, unmodified.

Instead, what happens is that before a method is executed the first time, the JITter steps in and translates the IL code into real binary machine code that will run on the actual CPU, typically into x86 compatible instructions.

The final binary code might not actually use a stack to hold local variables, it might use CPU registers. The virtual machine that the IL is targetting uses the stack as its registers, the x86 compatible cpus have multiple registers available.

As such, the code you posted might be translated into binary code that uses those registers instead of the stack, since those registers are faster than accessing memory.